# How to retain the value after GET in same page?

Tags: php

My page name is sym.php my problem is when I clicking this href below

```
<a href=sym.php?poscon=Face>Face</a>
   <?php
     echo '<br><td><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$otherspec.'" name="sym[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$spec.'"></td>';
     echo '<td align="">'.$spec.'</td>';
     if (!empty($_POST['sym'])) { 
         foreach($_POST['sym'] as $condition) {
             $condition = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condition);
             $p = mysqli_query($link,"select *   from  $tablename where PossibleCondition = '". $condition ."'");  
             echo "<b> ".$condition." </b> <br>" ;
             while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($p)) {
                 $spec = $r["Specialization"];
                 $spec1 = $r["Specialization1"];   
             }    
   ?>
```

This value should return after clicking the href on top what should I do? or function will I do. Thank you in advance.

```
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec ?>"> <u><?php echo $spec ?></u></a>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec1 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec1 ?></u></a>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec2 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec2 ?></a></u>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec3 ?>"> <u><?php echo $spec3 ?></a></u>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: ok you will get `$_GET['poscon'] = "Face"`, then what do you want to do next?

Comment: This value should return after clicking the href on top what should I do?

Comment: what are you trying to do? handle the query string server side? If so, you seem to be trying to use `POST` which will be empty. You seem to be trying to combine a form and a link.  What value should return? what do you mean by return?  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: This value should return after GET<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec ?>"> <u><?php echo $spec ?></u></a>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec1 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec1 ?></u></a>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec2 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec2 ?></a></u>
<a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec3 ?>"> <u><?php echo $spec3 ?></a></u>